# How to achieve "uber drop-off" like notification?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

1. I am tring to replicate uber's drop off dialog that shows in the homepage.
   I have already tried it using bubbles but couldn't make it work.

[image: Uber Drop Off Notification]

Comment: i'd advise you to focus on asking about one specific problem per question, you're welcome to create multiple questions but don't ask about multiple problems at once